# What should I use to implement the JBoss AOP aspect concepts

Tags: aop, jboss6.x

I am currently using JBoss app server 6 and using JBoss AOP aspects in my application. As I am migrating to my application to another app server, I need to implement aspects and I cannot use JBoss AOP. Could you please suggest what technology should I use to  implement the JBoss AOP aspect concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AspectJ. It is mature, independent of a certain app server, efficient and more powerful than JBoss AOP or Spring AOP.