# Please help on equivalent concept for JBoss AOP aspect

Tags: jboss, aop

I am using JBoss application server 6 and using JBoss AOP aspects in my application.

An example of aspect shown below:

```
public class DBAspect{

public Object accessDBConnection(FieldReadInvocation invocation) {
        return dbConnection;
    }

public Object accessDBConnection((FieldWriteInvocation invocation) {
    throw exception;
    }
}
```

Currently, these advice methods are applied to a private variable in class say DBUsage by binding it with this aspect.

I am migrating to a new application server and it is not supporting JBoss AOP. So, how do I implement this concept.

How can I implement this behavior. Please help.

Comment: Do you always ask similar questions [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26906118/1082681)? Hey man, you can **edit** questions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying field get/set pointcuts to private field does not sound like good application or aspect design to me. Maybe refactoring your application would be a better idea. Anyway, in AspectJ you can use `get()` and `set()` pointcuts in order to intercept field get/set actions. If you want to access private fields, you might need to use a `privileged aspect`.

- [AspectJ quick reference](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf)
- [Privileged aspects](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-privilege)
- [AspectJ pointcut types (incl. get/set)](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html)